# Finding people to critique web site designs

Tags: web, usability

There are firms which critique sites from the stand point of user experience and usability. They cost thousands. I am cheap and have little money for that! :)

I would like to get critiques from volunteer web designers who know a thing or two about good online experience and good web design.

Any online resources like forums where people look at your site upon request and give good genuine opinions without concentrating on the html which was used. (meaning losing the big picture and focusing on technical details. I don't want that).

A place where "[Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)" enthusiasts gather online, if such a place exists! (I will ask the author!)

Comment: I always found giving the site to someone with no industry experience to be a refreshing take on things, especially if I had to hand hold them through things.

Comment: That's one area to tackle it and you have to watch them work on it but they won't necessarily give YOU advice because they don't know what's wrong from right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FeedbackArmy](http://feedbackarmy.com)
will give you 10 responses for $10. I haven't tried them myself, but I've heard good things about them.

Comment: On face value, the feedback from FeedbackArmy seems fairly superficial. You will do better with real people (targeted users) interact with your site & getting their feedback = usability testing.

A heuristic review approach (like FeedbackArmy's offering) requires (i) heuristics suitable for evaluating your site & (ii) evaluators with extensive usability experience & skill. 

But still, they offering a service that is discount & usability testing / reviewing of any nature is better than nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get much more valuable feedback by doing a bit of testing with some real people, perhaps heading to a local coffee shop and asking for some opinions on whatever your building in exchange for coffee.